Changing frame styles of annotation with PyQGIS, e.g. setting the transparency to 0 %
With PyQGIS I want to create an Annotation, for each feature in a Layer.
For that I wrote this script (with the help from Programmatically adding annotations and changing some points):
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

# use the selected layer for the creation of the annotations
layer = iface. activeLayer()
iter = layer.getFeatures()


for feature in iter:
    # retrieve every feature with its geometry and attributes

    
    # get the values which should be written as the annotation and get them into
    # a html string

    # fetch attributes
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    
    # attrs is a list. It contains all the attribute values of this feature
    waypointText = attrs[2]
    
    # attributes for the html string
    font_size = "14px"
    color = "#000000"
    
    html = f'<p style="font-size:{font_size}; color:{color}; font-weight:bold;;"><strong> {str(waypointText)}</strong></p>'
    
    
    a = QgsTextAnnotation()
    c = QTextDocument()
    c.setHtml(html)
    a.setDocument(c)
    
    
    symbol = qgis.core.QgsMarkerSymbol()

    # set the color of the symbol marker
    symbol.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)) 
    
    # Set the outline width so no line is showing
    symbol_layer = symbol.symbolLayers()[0]
    symbol_layer.setStrokeWidth(0.0000000001)  # Adjust width as needed; 0 is bugged use number near 0
    
    
    a.setMarkerSymbol(symbol)
    
    # set the position of the annotation
    a.setFrameSize(QSizeF(100, 50))
    a.setMapLayer(layer)
    a.setFrameOffsetFromReferencePoint(QtCore.QPointF(-20, -20))
    a.setMapPosition(feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint())
    a.setMapPositionCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(layer.crs()))
    
    # adding the annotation to the map
    QgsProject.instance().annotationManager().addAnnotation(a)

The problem is that I do not want the frame to appear. I want it to appear transparent.
Here a picture how the annotation looks like with my script:

I want to change it, that the opacity is set to 0 %. So that it looks like this:

I would have looked into the PyQGIS documentation but it seems to be not working at this moment.
I use QGIS 3.34.

Just create a fill symbol with transparent fill and no outline, and set it to your annotations:
...
# Previous code inside your feature iterator loop
a.setMarkerSymbol(symbol)

# Additional lines
fill_symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '0,0,0,0', 'outline_style': 'no'})
a.setFillSymbol(fill_symbol)


Thank you, works perfect!
